# How Can I disable react native inner scroll view?

Tags: react-native

I have react native app which has tabs and scroll views, I want the outer scroll view to slide up to a certain point and when it reaches that height then the inner view can be scrolled. When the inner Scroll is at zero we can pull down the outer scroll view.

For example:

```
<Animated.ScrollView
    style={{ flex: 1 }}
    bounces={false}
    alwaysBounceVertical={false}
    nestedScrollEnabled={true}
    onScrollEndDrag={() => debounces()}

    onScroll={Animated.event([
      { nativeEvent: { contentOffset: { y: _scrollY } } },
    ])}
    scrollEventThrottle={16}
  >



      <Animated.View
        style={{
          height: SCROLL_HEIGHT,
          marginTop: scroll_view_stop,
          backgroundColor: "blue",
         flex:1,}}>

        <Tabs
          tabBarUnderlineStyle={{
            borderBottomWidth: 0,
            backgroundColor: Colors.SECONDARY,
          }}
        >
          <Tab
            heading={
              <TabHeading style={styles.tabHead}>
                <Text style={styles.tabHeadTitle}>Services</Text>
              </TabHeading>
            }
          >
          <ScrollView 
          bounces={false}

          onScroll={Animated.event([
            { nativeEvent: { contentOffset: { y: innerScroll } } },
          ])}
           scrollEventThrottle={16}
          // onScrollEndDrag={() => console.warn("dragd")}
          >
            <View style={{height:1000}}>

            <Text> fdsfl </Text>
            <Text> fdsfl </Text>
            </View>
          </ScrollView>



          </Tab>
          <Tab
            heading={
              <TabHeading style={styles.tabHead}>
                <Text style={styles.tabHeadTitle}>Reviews</Text>
              </TabHeading>
            }
          ></Tab>
          <Tab
            heading={
              <TabHeading style={styles.tabHead}>
                <Text style={styles.tabHeadTitle}>About </Text>
              </TabHeading>
            }
          ></Tab>
        </Tabs>
      </Animated.View>

  </Animated.ScrollView>
```

I tried to create a transparent View withing the outer scroll on top of the Main View so that when the user drags the tabs to the top of the screen it will be disabled and the user can scroll fine.

But there is no way to drag that scroll down again to its min position.

Please let me know if there a tip or if there is something that I might do to fix this thing.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Luckily I found this [Flat list scrolling with animation](https://snack.expo.io/@satya164/collapsible-header-with-tabview), which works well and that's exactly what I want

Hope this helps someone.

FYI, I think you need to install react-native-tab-view version ("0.0.74").